# Getting Promise Pending with Firebase and Express/Node.js

Tags: javascript, express, firebase, pug, firebase-realtime-database

I've run into some trouble working with Firebase. I'd like to retrieve data from my Firebase database using my Express server and pass that data as an object I can use in my Jade templates. I want to take data from two different endpoints and set that data to be the value of a key in my `firebaseData` object you'll see below. Instead of receiving an object with keys and the values I expect my two values are each `Promise {<pending>}`. I log my `firebaseData` object out in the console to see this and nothing is rendered in the DOM. Am I rendering the page too quickly?  Here is the code I am working with:

```
app.get("/cac", function(req, res){

  var firebaseData = {};

  function getFirebaseData(endpoint){
    return firebase.database().ref(endpoint).once("value", function(snapshot){
          return snapshot.val();
    });
  }

  firebaseData.members = getFirebaseData("CAC_Members");

  firebaseData.events = getFirebaseData("CAC_Events");

  console.log(firebaseData);
  res.render("cac", firebaseData);

});
```

In the console:

```
{ members: Promise { <pending> },
  events: Promise { <pending> } }
```

I haven't had any experiences with promises but I feel like what I'm doing should be working. Is there a better way to be doing this? I'd appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firebase data is loaded asynchronously. Promises are one way of dealing with this and they're a great fit for your need.

Your code needs to wait until all promises are fulfilled, which is very easy with `Promise.all()`:

```
app.get("/cac", function(req, res){

  var firebaseData = {};

  function getFirebaseData(endpoint){
    return firebase.database().ref(endpoint).once("value", function(snapshot){
          return snapshot.val();
    });
  }

  Promise.all([getFirebaseData("CAC_Members"), getFirebaseData("CAC_Events")]).then(function(snapshots) {
    firebaseData.members = snapshots[0];
    firebaseData.events = snapshots[1];
    console.log(firebaseData);
    res.render("cac", firebaseData);
  });
});
```

Comment: Woot! Thanks Frank. This worked out for me great, I appreciate the prompt and helpful response.

Comment: is the open squere bracket a mistake?

Comment: It was missing a closing `]` for the array passed into `Promise.all()`. Thanks for catching, I updated my answer.